# Scala error type mismatch

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find another way of avoiding a type mismatch error that looks more correct than the one I'm using right now.

Considering the list and the function, respectively:

```
var l = List[Int]()

def append[U](cmd: U) = {
        l = l :+ cmd
}
```

When interpreting the code above, I'm getting the following error:

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[Int]
                   l = l :+ cmd
                         ^
```

The way I fixed it, was by modifying the append function to work like this:

```
  def append[U](cmd: U) = {
    l = (l :+ cmd).asInstanceOf[List[Int]]
  }
```

Is there a way of defining the append function without the use of asInstanceOf?

Trying to be clearer, the goal was to create the class below

```
abstract class Cstruct{
  type T
  var value: T
  def append[U](value:U)
}
```

Cstruct should be built in a way that would be possible to define new classes that extends Cstruct but use different data structures for the value T. Like Cseq that uses a List of any type of elements, but should be possible to create a similar one using a Set or a Map.

```
class Cseq[U] (v: U) extends Cstruct{
  type T = List[U]
  var value: T = List[U](v)
  override def append[U](cmd: U) = {
    value = (value :+ cmd).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is `append` generic? You can only append `Int`s (or a supertype) to a `List[Int]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because your type variable `U` has no constraints, it could be any type - yet you try to add a value of type `U` to a list of `Int`.

Your fix is not type-safe. It will allow you to attempt to add for example a `String` to a `List[Int]`. The `asInstanceOf` makes the compile error go away, but you'll get a `ClassCastException` at runtime if you add a wrong type of object to the list.

Why does your method have a type parameter at all? If the list is always a `List[Int]`, then it should just take an `Int` instead of an `U`:

```
def append(cmd: Int) = {
  l = l :+ cmd
}
```

*edit* - You can do this:

```
abstract class Cstruct[U] {
  type T
  var value: T
  def append(value: U)
}

class Cseq[U](v: U) extends Cstruct[U] {
  type T = List[U]
  var value: T = List[U](v)

  override def append(cmd: U) =
    value = value :+ cmd
}
```

Note that in your own definition of `Cseq[U]`, the `U` in `override def append[U]` is a different type parameter than the one defined at `class Cseq[U]`. It just happens to have the same name `U`.

Comment: It won't always be List[Int], List[Int] was used as an example, the method append has a type parameter because it must be generic.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for.